# capture find command output to log file

Tags: shell, logging

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/cygdrive/d/splunk/finance"
LOG="/home/scripts/logCleanUp.log"
cat /dev/null>$LOG
date > $LOG
cd $path
find ./ -name "System*_*.log" -type f -exec rm -f {} \; >>$LOG 2>&1
du -sh $path >>$LOG
```

**Output File: /home/scripts/logCleanUp.log**

```
Mon, Apr 09, 2018 11:13:20 AM
109M    /cygdrive/d/splunk/finance
```

Output file shows only above 2 lines. However, I also want to capture find command output so that it tells me what all files have been deleted

Thanks,
Khus

Comment: #!/bin/bash

path="/cygdrive/d/splunk/finance"
LOG="/home/scripts/logCleanUp.log"
cat /dev/null>$LOG;


date>$LOG

cd $path


     find ./ -name "System*_*.log" -type f -exec rm -f {} \; >>$LOG 2>&1


     du -sh $path >>$LOG

Answer (score 1):

Add a `-print` to the find command

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/cygdrive/d/splunk/finance"
log="/home/scripts/logCleanUp.log"
{
  date
  find $path -name "System*_*.log" -type f -print -exec rm -f {} \; 
  du -sh $path
} > $log 2>&1
```

I took the liberty to put the commands in `{}`, so you need only one redirection and no initialize.

You should not use variablenames in uppercase, they are usually reserved for system variables. Just avoid the possible conflict.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know the power of {} and other syntactical corrections . it worked for me. Truly appreciate your time